# How to change the text color of the items in the AUtocomplete drop down ( for add new row) in Kendo Grid based on the status of the item?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

```
How to change the text color of the items in the AUtocomplete drop down ( for add new row) in Kendo Grid based on the status of the item?

I am working on a Kendo Grid. it has an Add new row button when clicked creates a blank row inline to grid. The input field is Autocomplete and data is of tyoe object.Fullname. I need to change the color of the values in this autocomplete dropdown based on the value of Object.Active.

Any suggestions please?

//code here
```

> ```
> @(Html.Kendo().Grid<....Models...VM>()
>         .Name("COOfficerVM")
>                             .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; " })
>                         .Columns(columns =>
>                         {
>                             columns.Bound(a => a.OfficerID).Hidden();
>                             columns.Bound(a => a.FullName).Width(100).Title("Credit Officer").ClientTemplate("#=
> ```
>
> getFormat(InActive,InActiveOfficer,FullName)#");
>                                   columns.Bound(a => a.OfficerNumber).Width(50).Title("Officer Number");
>                                   columns.Bound(a => a.UserID).Width(50).Title("User ID");
>
> ```
>                             columns.Bound(a => a.InActive).Title("Deleted").Width(50)
>                                 .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' disabled='disabled' value='#= InActive #' " +
>                                     "# if (InActive) { #" +
>                                         "checked='checked'" +
>                                     "# } #" +
>                                 "/>");
>                             columns.Command(commands =>
>                             {                            
>                                 commands.Edit().Text("Edit");
>                                 commands.Custom("Delete").Click("Delete");
>                             }).Width(50).Title("Edit");
>                         })
>
>                         .ToolBar(toolbar =>
>                         {
>                             toolbar.Create().Text("Add New");
>
>                         })
>             .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine ))
>                 .Events(e => e.Edit("onEdit"))
>             .Sortable()
>                 .Scrollable()
>              .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource        
>                 .Ajax()
>                     .Events(events => events
>                         .Error("error_handler")
>             )
>
>                 .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.OfficerID))
>                     .Create("_Insert", "COOfficer")
>                             .Read("_COOfficerGrid", "COOfficer")
>                     .Update("_Update", "COOfficer")
>                         .Destroy("_Delete", "COOfficer")
>         )
>             )</div>
> ```

// dropdown is calling Autocomplete function inside the controller

Comment: You can template your autocomplete items: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/autocomplete/template
Templates can contain code that conditionally outputs different html depending on properties of the item, such as 'Active' in your case. Please edit your question to include the html for your autocomplete if you need further guidance. Note that templating for autocomplete is marked as a 'new' feature at that link so may not be available depending on the version of Kendo UI you have installed.

Comment: NigelK, i have added grid code. it is using Kendo MVC grid...i am trying to understand what is happenning under the hood. How to change it..

Comment: Is it possible t catch the K-Autocomplete class and set color of all <li> inside it based on Astive or now..?